# Win10: Programatically/Automatically Email a file when it enters a Folder

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, automation

I'd like to automatically email a file, when it is put in a folder, I'm using Outlook 2013, and the folder would be on my local disk.

I'm not sure if it's possible to simply Open the email, ready to click "Send", or to actually send the email.

I've looked about, and there seems to be mainly proprietary software, which I won't be able to purchase.

Is this possible, with a `.BAT` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this real-time, i.e. a message should be composed the exact moment a file is put into a folder, I don't think it can be done without any 3rd party software.

What you could do is to create a scheduled task that runs every n seconds or minutes, and scans for new files. Then run a script such as the one written by Adam Nielsen: https://github.com/adam-nielsen/openOutlook/ This will create a message in Outlook ready to be sent.